# Why does address of ".rodata" section change at runtime?

Tags: c, memory, elf

I use a global array of 1000 const elements. I print the pointer of the array, in order to check the memory location of the array (resp.rodata).

```
// gcc rodataTEST.c -O0 -o rodataTEST
// size --format=SysV rodataTEST

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

const int DatenC[1000] = {  
94321, 
16225, 
//... 
-60803 }; 

int main()
{
    int a=42;
    int* hptr = malloc(sizeof(int));
    printf("Stack Ptr\t%p \n",(int *) &a );          //0x7fff0b7f1ebc 
    printf("Heap  Ptr\t%p \n",(int *) hptr);         //0x556e3ef78260 
    printf(".rodata\t\t%p \n",(const int*) DatenC);  //0x556e3e8df840 
    return 0;
}
```

The rodata is located at address *0x556e3e8df840* ie. below the base address of the heap which is to be expected. The command *size --format=SysV* confirms that the array is stored in the *.text* section of the ELF-file,
as can be seen in the red box of the picture  .
[image]

What I don't understand is the address, which is indicated in the red box of the picture [Printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gu8lZ.png). Resp. the address-column of the command *size --format=SysV* indicates that the rodata is located at address 2080 (0x820), however the pointer of *DatenC* clearly points to a completely different address (Despite the fact that *DatenC* clearly is stored in the rodata-section).

Could some please tell me, why the pointer *DatenC* does not correspond with the address provided by the command `size --format=SysV`.
I assume that `size --format=SysV`, is an offset to some address, or that it is a physical address and the address of pointer *DatenC* is of course the virtual address.

Many thanks for all replies.

Comment: What system is this?

Comment: One is address in memory at runtime, the other is offset into a file?

Comment: the program compiled for, and run on a Linux (OS). (ubuntu 18.04)

Comment: Because of [address space layout randomization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization), no static tool can tell you the absolute  address where this section will be located at runtime.  However the numbers shown by `size` don't make sense either as an offset in memory from the random base address, nor as offset into the file - in either case I think they ought to be page aligned.

Answer (score 0):

> Could some please tell me, why the pointer DatenC does not correspond with the address provided by the command size --format=SysV.

Because your system (by default) uses [position-independent executables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code#Position-independent_executables) (PIE), which are relocated *at runtime*.

To build a non-PIE executable, add `-no-pie` to your link line. Then the address printed by `size` will agree with actual runtime address.